# Creating a no Space string using pointers in C

Tags: c

I am trying to write a code that creates a string with no space. But my code doesn't work.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdbool.h>

bool SpaceDetect(char c)
{
     if (c == ' '|| c == '\n' || c == '\t')
         return true;
     return false;
}

char *NoSpacer(char* s)
{
     char* cs = s;
     while (*s != '\0')
     {
         if(SpaceDetect(*s))
         {
             s++;
             continue;
         }
         *cs = *s;
         cs++;
         s++;
     }
     *cs = '\0';
     return cs;
}

int main ()
{
     char test[] = " this is a test for me";
     printf("String with space is : %s\r\n", test);
     printf("Sting with no space is: %s\r\n", NoSpacer(test));
     return 0;
}
```

---

the output is as follow:

```
Stinng with space is : this is a test for me
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: Post true code and true output - recommend cut & paste.  "Stinng with space is ..." is not a believable put of `printf("String with space is : %s\r\n", test);`

Comment: I can't think of anywhere the `'\r'` would be required paired with `'\n'`? Not even on winders...

Comment: I cannot reproduce the segfault. Actually with a variant of Achals answer, there is not even a functional problem. Seeing the comment by chux I suspect that you are quite far faway from a [mcve]. Please crearte one.

Comment: Save cs or s in the beginning in some variable(you increment them both). Then return this pointer(which mush point at the beginning of the string!) and everything will work.

Comment: I mean char* tmp = cs. Then return tmp.

Comment: @purec Yes, that is the variant of Achals answer I also meant. How does that explain the segfault?

Comment: @Yunnosch there is no segfault, hence this question must be closed.

Comment: Note that `SpaceDetect` can be replaced with the standard [`isspace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isspace) which covers all ASCII whitespace.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala True. And I am trying to get that done, without answerers focusing on practically off-topic problems.

Comment: I can reproduce a problem with `printf("Sting with no space is: %s\r\n", NoSpacer(" this is a test for me"));`. That would not happen to be what your code actually is?

Answer (score 1):

This

```
cs++; /* this changes cs initial address where it points */
```

Instead of `cs++` use `cs[index]` and increments the `index` and store the content of `s` into `cs` without spaces.

For e.g

```
char *NoSpacer(char* s) {
        char* cs = s;
        int index = 0;
        while (*s != '\0') {
                if(SpaceDetect(*s)) {
                        s++;
                        continue;
                }
                cs[index] = *s; /* this is correct way */
                index+=1;
                //cs++; /* this is the problem */
                s++;
        }
        cs[index] = '\0';
        return cs;
}
```

Comment: OP's `*cs = '\0';
     return cs;` would return an empty string and not cause a seg-fault.  Something else is amiss in OP's question.

Comment: yes @chux true  `*cs = '\0';` `return cs;` doesn't causes seg.fault, this `printf("Sting with no space is: %s\r\n", NoSpacer(test));` may  prints nothing.

Comment: With the code shown by OP, segfault cannot be explained. It is unlikely that it is what OP is actually looking at. This answer only solves a functional problem not what OP is asking about, the segfault. Solving the segfault however seems impossible without an actual MCVE. NIcely spotted return value mistake though.

Comment: Agree @Yunnosch thanks for your appreciation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get a segfault, and I don't see anything which would cause one. Instead, I get an empty result.

```
$ ./test
String with space is :  this is a test for me
Sting with no space is:
```

The issue is `NoSpacer` returns a pointer to NULL.

```
 *cs = '\0';
 return cs;
```

`NoSpacer(test)` modifies `test` in place. It should return nothing. Instead, use `test` again.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>

void NoSpacer(char* s)
{
     char* cs = s;
     while (*s != '\0')
     {
         if(isspace(*s))
         {
             s++;
             continue;
         }
         *cs = *s;
         cs++;
         s++;
     }
     *cs = '\0';
}

int main ()
{
     char test[] = " this is a test for me";
     printf("String with space is : %s\r\n", test);
     NoSpacer(test);
     printf("Sting with no space is: %s\r\n", test);
     return 0;
}
```

Also note I'm using [the standard `isspace` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isspace) from [ctypes.h](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/C_character_classification).